# Import request fails, even when pip installed the package

Tags: pip

Pip is not installing the module for python correctly

I have upgraded python to 3.7.3 and creted a symbolic link to the new version.  I am trying o import the module  - requests, but it fails and gives a error.  I suspect my links are incorrect.

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

# ls -lrt /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 May 22 12:36 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/Python-3.7.3/python

 which pip
 /usr/local/bin/pip

 which pip3
 /usr/local/bin/pip3

# python -m pip install --user requests
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip

# python -m pip3 install --user requests
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip3


# pip3 install requests
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from requests) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.7)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


# python
Python 3.7.3 (default, May 22 2019, 12:25:12)
[GCC 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
>>>
```

I am expecting use the module in the Linux terminal.. Works fine on Windows - cmd.   Any advice appericted.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the ENV path variables to get around this issues

Good link is - https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux/